# Norms that $C([0,1])$ to be an incomplete normed space.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I searched all of norms that  $C([0,1])$ to be  incomplete normed space. But I found only $\|.\|_p$ (for every $1\leq p<\infty$).

Are you know another norm on  $C([0,1])$ that $C([0,1])$ to be  incomplete normed space?

Of course I saw once another incomplete norm on $C([0,1])$ except $\|.\|_p$ . unfortunately I do not remember correct form it. But it was  like to  $\|f\|=\sum \frac{|f(r_n)|}{\cdots}$ that $\{r_n\}$ is sequence of rational numbers in $[0,1]$.

Is there everyone  that know this norm correctly and exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a_n) \in \ell^1$ be a sequence such that $a_n > 0$ (you maybe had in mind $a_n = 2^{-n}$) for all $n \in \mathbb N$, let $(r_n)$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$. Then 
$$ f \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left|f(r_n)\right|\cdot a_n $$
is a norm on $C([0,1])$. The definiteness follows from the fact, that a continuous function, vanishing on $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ must vanish on the whole of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the norm you saw was something like $$\|f\|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|f(r_n)|}{2^n}$$
– where $(r_n)$ is any dense sequence in $[0,1]$, for example, one denumerating all the rationals in $[0,1]$. The factor $2^n$ in the denominator is there just to assure that the series converges. You could just as well put $n^2$ there, for example.

It turns out that a sequence $(f_k)$ converges in this norm to a function $f$ if and only if $f_k(r_n)\to f(r_n)$ for all $n$. (Try proving it yourself.) From this, you can probably find Cauchy sequences that don't converge; for a simple example, take a sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to the characteristic function of $[0,\frac12]$.

Comment: I believe I have a counterexample to the claim that $f_k(r_n) \to f(r_n)$ for all $n$ implies $f_k \to f$; it shows that even pointwise convergence everywhere isn't enough. Suppose we enumerate the dyadic rationals in $(0,1)$ as $r_n$ in the order $1/2, 1/4, 3/4, 1/8, 3/8, 5/8, 7/8,\dotsc$. This sequence is dense in $[0,1]$. Let each $f_k$ be continuous such that $f_k(x) = 0$ for all $x \notin (0,1/2^k)$, and such that $f(r_{2^k}) \equiv f(1/2^{k+1}) = 2^{2^k}$. Then we have pointwise convergence everywhere to $0$, but $\|f_k\| \geq 1$ for all $k$.

Comment: @epimorphic You're right, I was a bit hasty there. However, the claim is true for bounded sequences (bounded in the usual uniform norm, that is). And that is sufficient for the present purpose of making a divergent Cauchy sequence. Thanks for point out the mistake. (I am not going to edit the answer. Let future readers look at the comments.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several generalizations of $L^p$ spaces:

Weighted $L^p$ spaces. A function $w\colon[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ is called a wight.
$$
\|f\|_{L^p(w)}=\Bigl(\int_0^1|f(x)|^pw(x)\,dx\Bigr)^{1/p},\quad 1\le p<\infty.
$$

[Orlicz's spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birnbaum%E2%80%93Orlicz_space)

[Lorentz spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_space)